vba selenium webautomate but chart undefined
I manually accessed the webpage wantrich.chinatimes.com/tw-market/listed/stock/3167, and the chart loads completely without any issues. However, when I use Selenium to access the same page, the chart is not visible and shows "undefined
dynamic chart shown undefined
update: The website has restrictions on selenium.  how to by pass it ??
Dim Mychorme As Selenium.ChromeDriver

Sub Take_ScreenShot_Entirepage_Cropped()

    Dim wdh As Integer
    Dim hght As Integer
    Dim topOffset As Integer
    Dim bottomOffset As Integer
    Dim filePath As String
    
    topOffset = 500  ' 
    bottomOffset = 500  ' 
    filePath = ThisWorkbook.Path
    
    Set Mychorme = New Selenium.ChromeDriver
    
    With Mychorme    
        .Timeouts.ImplicitWait = 5000
        .Start
        .Get "https://wantrich.chinatimes.com/tw-market/listed/stock/3167"
                
        wdh = .ExecuteScript("return document.body.scrollWidth")
        hght = .ExecuteScript("return document.body.scrollHeight")  
        .Window.SetSize wdh, hght - topOffset - bottomOffset        
        .ExecuteScript "window.scrollTo(0, " & topOffset & ");"        
        Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:03"))        
        .TakeScreenshot.SaveAs filePath & "\screenCapture_Entirepage_Cropped.png"        
        .Quit
        
    End With

End Sub


a short answer: you shouldn't try to bypass without authorization.
Try to reach out their customer service. sometimes they can offer an access through API
"Based on factors such as information security and protecting the value of website content, this site gives permission to stop access to uncertified robots, crawlers and other unnatural human access behaviors."
"How to remove restrictions
Please stop non-human access to this website in the network environment, record the following blocked connection information, provide contact information to contact our customer service, and request us to lift the access restrictions.
In addition, if you have business needs and need a certified crawler to access this website in a non-human way, please contact our customer service and we will have a business window to explain the cancellation to you."
